# MappingException: The target-entity cannot be found after renaming class. Caching issue on production environment

Tags: php, symfony, caching, doctrine-orm

I'm using Symfony 4.4 with doctrine 2.0.8
I've recently been refactoring a lot of our code and some of that involves renaming certain class names. This all works perfectly fine until we deploy to our production environment, where I'm getting MappingExceptions because it keeps trying to find old class names.

E.g.

Relationship in the namespace `App\Entity\PortalUser`
has been renamed/moved to `App\Entity` and renamed to `PortalUserRelationship.php`.

Locally all of this work!

But once I try to `bin/console cache:clear --env=prod` I get the following error:

`The target-entity App\Entity\PortalUser\Relationship cannot be found in 'App\Entity\PortalUser#portalUserRelationships'.`

Of course this makes sense because this doesn't exist anymore at that location but somehow doctrine is still looking for the Entity in the wrong place?

This is the relation code just to prove that it's all correct.

```
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\PortalUserRelationship", mappedBy="portalUser", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private Collection $portalUserRelationships;
```

So somewhere there's something making it impossible to clear the production cache and I have found no way on how to clear this cache.

Mind you `bin/console clear:cache --env=dev` works, but `bin/console clear:cache --env=prod` fails.

I have tried the following to no avail.

```
php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-query
php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-result
```

I've also tried removing the entire `var/cache` folder, doesn't help.

I've tried restarting the apache2 server, nope.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `PortalUser\Relationship` Somewhere you have that extra backslash.  I might add that the most common source of these sorts of errors is when the php filename containing the entity class does not match the class name itself typically because of case sensitivity but could also be because of forward slash vs backslash issues.  Things that work under Windows might not work under Linux.

Comment: I'm running the same environment as the server. Also it just seems to be an issue of doctrine not realizing something has changed. The mapping is correct according to `bin/console doctrine:schema:validate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following to `doctrine.yml` for the failing environments fixed the issue.

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really find a solution.

`bin/console doctrine:mapping:info --env=dev` was showing [OK] on everything
`bin/console doctrine:mapping:info --env=prod` was showing 2 mappings errors on the fields I renamed.

I have a feeling that composer autoload was using the wrong/outdated file to look for the files.

I have run `composer dump-autoload` to no avail.
I have grep'ed my entire system to look for the string that was being used in the mapping error but it couldn't be found.

I have cleared all the doctrine/symfony/composer cache, nothing changed.
I have restarted apache2/php-fpm, nothing changed.

The only thing that fixed it was changing the name of my field to anything but `$portalUserRelationships`, e.g. `$portalUsersRelationships` worked.

I'm still 100% sure it's just the system messing up looking for mapping in an outdated file, but I couldn't quite figure out where it was getting the data from.

Anyway for anyone with a similar issue, try renaming your fields and hope to god it works.